# angular.js: ReferenceError: up is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I'm working on upload function for my project, my button are including functions upload and submit. As soon as I click on upload I'm getting a error in developer console:

> angular.js:13236 ReferenceError: up is not defined

reference on this error says that the problem in this line

```
$scope.$watch("up.file", function() { if (up.file) up.submit() });
```

exactly in `if (up.file)` but in meantime, everything works fine. Upload function works and all files are uploading. So I appreciate if someone could explain me where is my mistake?

```
  app.controller('uploadCtrl',['$scope', '$http','Upload','$window',function($scope, $http,Upload,$window){
    var vm = this;
    vm.submit = function(){ //function to call on form submit
        if (vm.upload_form.file.$valid && vm.file) {//check if from is valid

            //console.log(vm.file.name);
            vm.upload(vm.file); //call upload function
            //vm.file.name = prompt("put you name");
        }
        $scope.$watch("up.file", function() { if (up.file) up.submit() });
    };

    vm.upload = function (file) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: '/upload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
            data:{file:file} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        }).then(function (resp) { //upload function returns a promise
            if(resp.data.error_code === 0){ //validate success
                $window.alert('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ' uploaded.');
            } else {
                $window.alert('an error occured');
            }
        }, function (resp) { //catch error
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
            $window.alert('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            console.log(evt);
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
            vm.progress = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% '; // capture upload progress
            setTimeout(10000);
        }).then (function() {
            $http.get('/compare').success(function() {
                setTimeout(function() { alert("success!"); }, 5000);
                // url was called successfully, do something
                // maybe indicate in the UI that the batch file is
                // executed...
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `vm.file` ?

Comment: up.file isn't declared anywhere, I think like loan said you mean if(vm.file)...

Comment: @haakon319 I fixed and now getting angular.js:13236 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":{}}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`up` variable is not defined in your controller. Instead, `vm` is defined.

So, use `vm.file` and `vm.submit`.

**Edit**:
You are defining your `watch` expression in the `submit` method, and you are calling the `submit` method from the `watch` expression.

You should define the `watch` outside of the `submit` method, like the following:

```
    vm.submit = function(){ //function to call on form submit
        if (vm.upload_form.file.$valid && vm.file) {//check if from is valid

            //console.log(vm.file.name);
            vm.upload(vm.file); //call upload function
            //vm.file.name = prompt("put you name");
        }
    };

    $scope.$watch("vm.file", function() { if (vm.file) vm.submit() });
```

Comment: Now I'm getting angular.js:13236 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":{}}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"up.file","newVal":"..."}]]

Comment: @Anton I'm glad that it helped.